"Advanced section/subsection" custom command produces unexpected numbering behaviour
I am attempting to create new commands for "advanced sections/subsections" (similar to what you might see in a textbook, where a "starred section" indicates an advanced topic or a section you can skip over on first reading.)
So far, I have cobbled together commands that place the star next to the section/subsection number in both the document itself and the ToC. However, there is a strange side effect where:

after using the "advanced section" command, the following subsection does not display the subsection number

after using the "advanced subsection" command, the following sections always display a "useless" subsection number of .0


Interestingly, the ToC entries behave exactly as expected, with no numbering issues. So, what could be causing this unexpected behaviour in the document itself?
I have included below a MWE illustrating this behaviour. (The numerous sections/subsections are meant to illustrate different permutations of using "regular" and "advanced" section/subsection commands.)
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\advsection}[2][section]{%
    \def\@seccntformat##1{\protect\llap{\large*}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \let\protect\mtnumberline\protect\numberline%
        \def\protect\numberline{%
            \hskip0pt%
            \global\let\protect\numberline\protect\mtnumberline%
            \protect\llap{\normalfont\normalsize*}%
            \protect\mtnumberline%
        }%
    }%
    \csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
    \def\@seccntformat##1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
}
\newcommand{\advsubsection}[2][subsection]{%
    \def\@seccntformat##1{\protect\llap{\large*}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{%
        \let\protect\mtnumberline\protect\numberline%
        \def\protect\numberline{%
            \hskip0pt%
            \global\let\protect\numberline\protect\mtnumberline%
            \protect\llap{\normalfont\normalsize*}%
            \protect\mtnumberline%
        }%
    }%
    \csname #1\endcsname{#2}%
    \def\@seccntformat##1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{My first chapter}
    \section{My first section}
    Blah
    \advsection{My second section}
    Blah
    \section{My third section}
    Blah
    \advsection{My fourth section}
    Blah
    \subsection{My first subsection}
    Blah
    \advsubsection{My second subsection}
    Blah
    \subsection{My third subsection}
    Blah
    \advsubsection{My fourth subsection}
    Blah
    \section{My fifth section}
    Blah
    \subsection{My first subsection}
    Blah
\end{document}





Incidentally, you can simplify the definition of \advsubsection to be \newcommand\advsubsection[2][subsection]{\advsection[#1]{#2}}, given that the two macros you defined have practically the same replacement text.

The problem is the line where you redefined \@seccntformat. Your code looks like
\def\@seccntformat##1{\protect\llap{\large*}\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}

note that you typed in the definition the#1 instead of the##1, and similarly for the definition that restores the original definition of \@seccntformat. Since you were able to write the code above you probably can figure out why this is a problem. If you change in all four occurrences to the##1 your code works as expected.

That the TOC is not impacted is because in latex.ltx the section numbers in the TOC is not printed via \@seccntformat (as you already found out since you had to create your own \numberline macro to add the *).

Thank you! Amazing how my eyes manage to glaze over the smallest errors and completely miss them.
